# Pontiac solstice 2006 manual starter

Tags: clutch

It wont start in neutral unless you turn the key and mess with the stick at the same time, usually takes 5 or 6 tries to get it to catch. I have no idea what the problem is

Comment: Sounds like a faulty neutral safety switch.

Comment: If the clutch must be depressed to start the engine, it might also be a faulty or misadjusted clutch switch.